# Trouble Converting Color Image to Grayscale Using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib

I'm trying to convert a color image to `grayscale`(black and white) using `OpenCV` in Python, but I'm encountering an issue where the output is not as expected. Here's the code I'm using:

```py
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from skimage import io
%matplotlib inline

imageUploader1image = io.imread('https://www.simplilearn.com/ice9/free_resources_article_thumb/what_is_image_Processing.jpg')
imageUploader1cvtColorImage = cv2.cvtColor(imageUploader1image, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY)
plt.imshow(imageUploader1cvtColorImage)
plt.show()
```

I am expecting the GRAY image but it returns:

[image: this image].

Comment: use `plt.gray()` to set the (display) colormap to grayscale

Comment: It seems unlikely that a JPEG image would have an alpha (A) channel, so converting RGBA2GRAY seems incorrect. Why do you load the image with `skimage` when you already have OpenCV installed which can read it itself?

Comment: `plt.imshow(arr, cmap='gray')`

Comment: The conversion is just fine, you're displaying the result incorrecty.

Comment: What do you need to import numpy for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're converting the image correctly, it's just that you're displaying it wrong. You need to set the colormap to grayscale, like this:

```py
# load the image here

plt.gray()
plt.imshow(imageUploader1cvtColorImage)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could change the colormap like this:

```py
# load the image here

plt.imshow(imageUploader1cvtColorImage, cmap="gray")
plt.show()
```

Output:
[image: grayscale picture produced]